# PostgreSQL - PostGIS query optimization

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgis, pgrouting

I have a query which creates an input to `pgRouting` `pgr_drivingDistance` function:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_edge AS                   
SELECT 
    e."Id" as id,
    e."Source" as source,
    e."Target" as target,
    e."Length" / (1000*LEAST("Speed", "SpeedMin")/60) as cost
FROM    "Edge" e,
        "SpeedLimit" sl
WHERE   sl."VehicleKindId" = 1
        AND e.the_geom && 
            ST_MakeEnvelope(
                x1-(1000*GREATEST("Speed", "SpeedMax")/60)*13, 
                y1-(1000*GREATEST("Speed", "SpeedMax")/60)*13, 
                x1+(1000*GREATEST("Speed", "SpeedMax")/60)*13,
                y1+(1000*GREATEST("Speed", "SpeedMax")/60)*13, 3857)
        AND sl."RoadCategoryId" = e."CategoryId";
```

In the `WHERE` clause I calculate the same thing several times to get bounding box coordinates.

I tried to put calculations into `FROM` part and use alias for calculated column, but then whole execution time increases twice.

`Edge` table is quite large (1 milion) and `SpeedLimit` is several dozen record.

Is there any way to enhance this query?

Comment: Where are x1, y1 coming from in this query. What does explain show?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended way to join tables using `JOIN` syntax. And then later restrict given set wit `WHERE`. What is ST_MakeEnvelope? You can use Index on expression in PostgreSQL ;) 
[Expression indexes in PostgreSQL](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/05/29/postgres-indexes-expression-or-functional-indexes/)

Since you are using expressions you might benefit from them.
And you might use [Explain analyize](http://explain.depesz.com/) to notice your bottlenecks in the query

Comment: I read there's no performance gain when joining using `JOIN`. ST_MarkeEnvelope is PostGIS function to create rectange of specific extent. The columns used for joining are indexed.

Comment: I was talking about expression indexes, since you have a few expressions in your query. `JOIN` adds to clarity of the query. :)